# Live streaming or on Demand content (HLS, HTTP Range Requests)

Tags: streaming, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm trying to deal with streaming (or rather Audio on Demand) in browsers and mobile applications. Some questions arise that are not very successful in finding a concrete answer. Maybe someone will tell me.

1. What is the feature of [HLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8216) and is it needed in the case of
   Audio on Demand?
2. What is HLS for if there is an [HTTP Range Requests](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7233)
   specification?
3. Or does HLS use HTTP Range Requests internally?

Thanks for answers!

Comment: Look-up progressive download vs. streaming. If the server supports HTTP range requests then you can use `EXT-X-BYTERANGE` in HLS (protocol version 4+).

Comment: @aergistal Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It depends: HLS is not always needed for streaming audio on demand.
   HLS enables you to have multiple quality levels (different bitrates) of the same content.
   For example on a metered cellular connection you may want to use low bandwidth (like AAC HEv2 at 32 kBits/s).
   For WiFi or wired unlimited connections you may to stream with 256 kBits/s.
   With HLS you can stick all your different quality levels into one package.
2. Normally for HLS on demand you would create one file per quality level and the HLS playlist would tell you the byte offset and length were to find the chunks - so that you can seek. Your client would read the playlist - get the offset and length of the chunk to read and then perform a HTTP range request. So single file HLS streams go together with HTTP range requests.
3. HTTP range request must be supported by the HTTP server hosting the single file HLS streams and the client/player must execute range request. So - yes - HTTP range requests are part of the system.

If the HLS streams are stored in lot's of little chunks - more common for live streaming - HTTP range requests are not used.

Comment: Thanks for long answer! Well then if I have only single mp3 file without different bitrates I can just to distribute it as a static file by the server, and the client will already request the necessary chunks (by HTTP Range Requests), right? So i get pseudo streaming with random access in timline.

Comment: It would still be better to wrap the mp3 file inside an mp4 container. An mp4 has additional metedata needed for seeking. There is no way to know how to byte range into an mp3 to seek to a specific time.

Comment: @szatmary And it still does not require additional protocols, right? Is it just that a browser (for example) will have the possibility of random access over a time line? But please explain the following behavior: Why when I open the mp3 file in the browser, the server first gives a response 200 with `Content-Length: 115131081`, then the browser asks `Range: bytes = 0-` and the server gives him the whole file or not?? And then, as you move along the track, the browser inquires from the server pieces of `Range: bytes = 4685824-`. Where in this case is the optimization?

Comment: @ФёдорЕрастов - accurate random access depends on how you create your MP3 file and how well the player is implemented. I would make the mp3 file with constant bitrate and populate the length metadata (ID3 TLEN). Now the player can do a HTTP HEAD request to get the complete file size, followed by reading the length in seconds from the ID3 tag TLEN at the beginning of the file. Now the player can approximate the byte offset for random access.

Comment: @MarkusSchumann Okey, I got it, if the server supports partial content, then the client player is responsible for the quality of work and for optimizing requests. Or use mp4, which contains metadata about ranges. Or use a ready-made protocol.